# Widget column bug when the column is hidden

Tags: extjs, grid, widget

I have a problem with widgetcolumns. When I hide a column, the other widgets in the grid don't work properly. In my application, I need to dynamically hide and show a column of widgets while keeping the other widgets running

**My fiddle:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dbk
Select value in tagfield. Press the 'Hide Num Column' button and try select a value in the Phone field. In the console you will see that when we hide a column, onWidgetAttach is run an infinite number of times

Any ideas  how to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the widget column so you can edit cells I would suggest using
[cell editing](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#cell-editing)
or row editing
[row editing](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#row-editing)